# Change state using redux in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is my component(react) which include rematch(Re play or play again) button.

```
  render() {
    const rematchTitle = formattedMessage('App.rematch');

    return (
        <div className='modal-footer'>
          <a className='btn'>{rematchTitle}</a>
        </div>
        );
  }
```

I want to give click event to that button.And when user click that (rematch-play again)button I want to trigger ready state(I want to change state to ready when user click that button).Because previous developer developed ready state and it works very well(ready state has reducers,actions...).I could not access previous developer and I am new at the redux.

I try to give onclick event to that button but this.props is not work.Where can I bind or set this.props?Should I add a new action as name reMatch
 and reducer as name reMatch?Where should I set this.props?In action?Or reducer?Or components?

```
 const { onPlayAgain } = this.props;
     let PlayAgain = '';
    const rematchlabel = <FormattedMessage message="app.rematch"/>;
      PlayAgainButton = (
        <a onClick={onPlayAgain } className={buttonStyleClassColored(colorBlue)}> {rematchlabel}</a>
      );
```

here is my component code

```
    import $ from 'jquery';
import React from 'react';

import { FormattedMessage } from 'util/IntlComponents';

import OkeyMatchResult from './OkeyMatchResult';

import { RoomState } from 'constants/AppConstants';


function formattedMessage(message) {
  return <FormattedMessage message={message}/>;
}

class OkeyMatchResultDialog extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    const currentRoomState = this.props.roomState;
    const nextRoomState = nextProps.roomState;




    if (currentRoomState === RoomState.PLAYING
      && nextRoomState === RoomState.END) {

      $('#matchResultModal').openModal({
        opacity: 0.5
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const matchEndTitle = formattedMessage('room_title.match_end');
    const rematchTitle = formattedMessage('room_title.rematch');
    const backToLobbyTitle = formattedMessage('room_title.back_tolobby');

    const { matchResult } = this.props;

    let PlayAgainButton = '';
    PlayAgainButton = (
       <a onClick={alert('slm')} > {rematchTitle}</a>
      );

    return (
      <div id='matchResultModal'
           className='matchresult-modal modal modal-fixed-footer'>
        <div className='modal-content'>
          <h4 className='center'>{matchEndTitle}</h4>
          <OkeyMatchResult matchResult={matchResult}/>
        </div>

        <div className='modal-footer'>
          <a className='btn side-by-side'>{backToLobbyTitle}</a>
          <a className='btn'>{PlayAgainButton}</a>
          <a className='btn'>{rematchTitle}</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default OkeyMatchResultDialog;
```

Comment: Could you post your full component?

Comment: @Austio I edited question and I added full component code.I want to add play again buton and if user click that buton I want to trigger ready action or ready reducer(because ready works very well).This is multiplayer game code.If user click ready the game start.This component works after game end.It show user points and play again buton...

Comment: How are you connecting this to redux?

Comment: how can I learn that in project? @Austio here is project files http://i.hizliresim.com/LAB2BZ.png  Do you use facebook or twitter?Can you connect me please just a minute..

Comment: @Austio I am connecting to redux with dispatch

Answer (score 0):

The `react-redux` library makes it easy to add this functionality. It provides a `connect` method which returns a React component which wraps the original presentational component and adds functions which have access to Redux to the original components's `props`. In the code below I've only injected one-way binding (React -> Redux) but it's simple to add the opposite direction (look up the `mapStateToProps` argument of `connect`).

Edited component (not tested):

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'util/IntlComponents';
import OkeyMatchResult from './OkeyMatchResult';
import { RoomState } from 'constants/AppConstants';

function formattedMessage(message) {
  return <FormattedMessage message={message}/>;
}

// This should return functions which internally use the Redux dispatch method (the dispatch dependency will be injected by react-redux)
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    var rematchAction = {}; // Define your "rematch" Redux action here
    return {
        onRematch: function () => {
            dispatch(rematchAction); // This will dispatch the action to your Redux store
        }
    }
};

// This creates an instance of OkeyMatchResultDialog with the object returned by mapDispatchToProps injected into its props
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(OkeyMatchResultDialog);

// This stays a purely presentational component (not aware of Redux)
class OkeyMatchResultDialog extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    const currentRoomState = this.props.roomState;
    const nextRoomState = nextProps.roomState;

    if (currentRoomState === RoomState.PLAYING
      && nextRoomState === RoomState.END) {

      $('#matchResultModal').openModal({
        opacity: 0.5
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const matchEndTitle = formattedMessage('room_title.match_end');
    const rematchTitle = formattedMessage('room_title.rematch');
    const backToLobbyTitle = formattedMessage('room_title.back_tolobby');

    const { matchResult } = this.props;

    let PlayAgainButton = '';
    PlayAgainButton = (
       <a onClick={this.props.onRematch} > {rematchTitle}</a> // Bound to the injected Redux-aware function
      );

    return (
      <div id='matchResultModal'
           className='matchresult-modal modal modal-fixed-footer'>
        <div className='modal-content'>
          <h4 className='center'>{matchEndTitle}</h4>
          <OkeyMatchResult matchResult={matchResult}/>
        </div>

        <div className='modal-footer'>
          <a className='btn side-by-side'>{backToLobbyTitle}</a>
          <a className='btn'>{PlayAgainButton}</a>
          <a className='btn'>{rematchTitle}</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```